# Can't delete Tortoise SVN meta file after Java writes to it

Tags: java, svn, windows-7, tortoisesvn, java-io

I made a simple Java utility to do some simple operations on a source project folder (checked out from SVN). For some reason after Java copies or changes the files, I can't delete the SVN meta data files. I use Tortoise SVN and I'm running Win7. I can copy/delete the folder with file explorer before Java touches it. Things I've tried:

- Using FileUtils to read and write
- Using just plain java io (closing files streams)
- Rebooting (still can't delete!)
- Turning off the cache on SVN and rebooting
- I can't clean-up, update or checkout over the project because Tortoise SVN says the meta data is corrupt

Now I've got 8 folders on my machine that I can't delete and rebooting doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `7-Zip File Manager` in your machine, try to use it to delete

Comment: I don't and worse... I can't. Policy here.

Answer (score 0):

The svn meta data files may in readonly state by default, you can try to adjust the read-write property before delete it in java.

Comment: In windows I did a right-click > Properties and the file is not read-only. I checked the source file and the undeletable copied version.